# Importing private submodule in swift file caused me error

Tags: objective-c, swift

**Here is the modulemap file** :

```
framework module Framework
{
    requires objc, objc_arc

    umbrella header "Header.h"

    export *
    module * { export * }

    explicit framework module Private
    {
        umbrella header "Header-Private.h"
    }
}
```

**how i imported it in swift file** :

```
import Framework.Private
```

**Now i've got this error** :

> @import Framework.Private;  @import of module 'Framework.Private' in
>   implementation of 'Framework'; use #import

Answer (score 0):

i think module map file will have some change

```
framework module <ProjectName> {
    umbrella header "ProjectName.h"
    export *
    module * { export * }

    explicit module ProjectName_Private {
        private header “<headerName>.h”

        link “staticLibName” // external static Library 
        export *
    }
}
```